# Can someone identify what's wrong with the following code? i am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java

```
   @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    JButton current;
    int turn=0;
    for(int i=0; i< buttons.length;i++){ 
        for(int j =0; j<buttons.length; j++){
            while(event.getSource().equals(buttons[i][j])){
            if(turn==0){
                current=buttons[i][j];
                current.setText("X");//current sets the text i,j to x.
                turn++;
                }
            else if(turn==1){
            current=buttons[i][j];
            current.setText("O");
            turn--;

                }
            }
        }//end j
    }//end i
}//end actionperformed.
```

okay, so i am trying make turns between x and o, so this method is the actionperformed one  but for some reason when i run the program it always freeze at the point when i click on the button. i think i messed up nested for loops(not entirely sure how it is executed) with the while loop.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code ?

Comment: Most likely and infinite loop @ `while(event.getSource().equals(buttons[i][j]))` add a `syso` statement to see if it ever exists the loop.

Comment: is there a better way to write this?

Comment: @Igor Konoplyanko, debugging doesn't work the program has to be terminated by task manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three loops, but you don't need any. What you want, if I understand correctly, is to set the text of the clicked button to X or O depending on the value of `turn`. And the clicked button is returned by `event.getSource()`. So the method should simply be:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    JButton clicked = (JButton) event.getSource();
    if (turn == 0) {
        clicked.setText("X");
        turn++;
    }
    else {
        clicked.setText("O");
        turn--;
    }
}
```

Note that given that turn can only have two values, you should make it a boolean:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    JButton clicked = (JButton) event.getSource();
    clicked.setText(turn ? "X" : "O");
    turn = !turn;
}
```

Comment: Agree with this answer, loops are not needed

Answer (score 0):

You are using `buttons.length` horizontally and vertically but your number of buttons is different than your number of columns/rows. In fact this number is the number of columns multiplied by number of rows. Try to use sqrt on this number.

Also instead of the integer variable `turn` you should use a boolean, and after each turn write: `turn = !turn`.

Edit: Moreover I don't understand why are you using the `while`.